# NetworkX OutEdgeView to list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, networkx

I need to covert networkx edges' OutEdgeView data to a list.

I remember the `graph.edges(data=True)` used to return a list like `[u,v,{data}]`. But now the networks returns something `OutEdgeView([u,v,{data}])`. How could I get the original kind of list?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Networkx recently moved to version 2.0 from 1.11. You should read the [migration guide](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/release/migration_guide_from_1.x_to_2.0.html).

In this case the guide provides an example:

```
>>> D = nx.DiGraph()
>>> D.add_edges_from([(1, 2), (2, 3), (1, 3), (2, 4)])
>>> D.nodes
NodeView((1, 2, 3, 4))
>>> list(D.nodes)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> D.edges
OutEdgeView([(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (2, 4)])
>>> list(D.edges)
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (2, 4)]
```

In general if you need to convert `X` to a list, you use `list(X)`.

This works for your case where you've used `data=True` as well.